# Why doesn't the second function gets called when onclick event handling mechanism is initiated?

Tags: javascript

Consider the snippet,

```
<input type="button" value="Press Me!" id="my" onclick="return executeX(); executeY()">
<script>
    function executeX() {
        alert("in X");
        return true;
    }

    function executeY() {
        alert("in Y");
    }
</script>
```

Even though ***true*** is ***returned*** from ***first function***, why doesn't the control forwards to ***executeY()*** within ***onclick***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&&` to combine them:

```
onclick="return executeX() && executeY();"
```

The short-circuiting of `&&` ensures that `executeY()` will only be called if `executeX()` returns truth.

Comment: uhh,  nice one Barmar

Comment: @Barmar : Were I living close to your location, I would have dropped by to thank you personally for this amazing answer. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Because in your onclick handler you are returning with the result of the first function. It's like a function: once you return, no other lines will be performed.

Comment: Thank you too for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you started your inline javascript with `return`. Therefore, as soon as the first function executed its result was returned.

Either remove the return or have the second function called at the end of the first function.

```
            function executeX(){
                alert("in X");
                executeY();
                return true;
            }   

            function executeY(){
                alert("in Y");
            }
```

Comment: The requirement was to call executeY only when true is returned from executeX. That means I need to move the conditional logic inside executeX and if true is returned call executeY from within executeX.

Comment: Thank you too for helping me out.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari, glad to :)

Answer (score 0):

you return a value(`executeX()`) before calling the second function(`executeX()`).

```
function example() {
    //Do Something
    return /*Return Something*/;
    //this Code will not be executed
}
```

possible solution:

```
<input type="button" value="Press Me!" id="my" onclick="function(){ executeY(); return executeX(); }">
```